# How to select a row with latest date and time

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a text file (space as delimiter) as shown below:

```
Date           Time---------OtherFields-------Source IP   Destination IP 

2014-11-24  12:58:59.290                      1.2.3.4         5.6.7.8

2014-11-24  12:59:01.402                      1.2.3.8         5.6.7.8

2014-11-24  13:00:01.542                      12.14.25.1      5.6.7.8

2014-11-25  14:00:02.5                        12.14.25.2      5.6.7.8

2014-11-25  15:00:01.542                      12.14.25.1      6.7.8.9

2014-11-25  16:00:01.542                      12.14.25.5      6.7.8.9
```

For Destination IP 5.6.7.8, I want to select a row with latest date and time and save it in a new text file for further processing. Same thing applies to all different Destination IP addresses. 
There are tons of rows like this.

The **desired output** should be like this.

```
2014-11-25  14:00:02.5                        12.14.25.2      5.6.7.8

2014-11-25  16:00:01.542                      12.14.25.5      6.7.8.9
```

No logic is clicking to me.Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for dest in $(awk '{print $NF}' mylogfile | sort | uniq)
do
  grep ${dest} mylogfile | sort -k1 -k2 | tail -1
done


1    $(awk '{print $NF}' mylogfile | sort | uniq)
```

print the last field of each line in logfile, which is your destrination IP.
sort it so that identical ip addresses are in consecutive blocks.
uniq is to print only one instance of identical blobk of lines

```
2 & 4   do ... done
```

I think these are self explanatory. The general loop construct

```
3    grep ${dest} mylogfile | sort -k1 -k2 | tail -1
```

find lines with one IP address (assumes this ip address is not repeating itself in any other field but the last one), sort on field 1 first and then field 2, latest of the date/time stamp falls into the last line. `tail -1` catches this last line

Comment: Could you please explain the code

Comment: @MelBurslan, this is a great answer! However, I feel that the `grep ${dest} mylogfile` part may cause some issue - theoretically, the IP value we grep can be found in the `source IP` as well. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following `awk`:

```
awk '{ x = $1" "$2; if (x > a[$4]) { a[$4] = x; b[$4] = $0; } } END { for (i in b) { print b[i]; } }' file
```

But as it holds two arrays in memory may be not very useful for very big files.